# Disable submit button till filling ckeditor field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form and i used CKEditor in textareas to format the content of textarea e.g. bullets, font color, size etc.

i have written below JS code to disable the submit button till filling all some specific fields. JS code works on text fields but not in textarea field because of CKEditor.

If possible i want to also make this JS code to work on textareas where CKEditors are used.

**JS Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

$(function() {

$(function() {
    $('#sbtbtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});


$('input[type=text],textarea,input[type=password]').keyup(function() {

    if ($('#target1').val() !='' &&
    $('#editor1').val() != '') {

        $('#sbtbtn').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#sbtbtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
    });


    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" class="ara-form" name="theform" >
                <header>Enter Job Details</header>

                <fieldset>                  
                    <div class="row">
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                            <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" id="target1" placeholder="Job Title" name="positiontitle">
                                <div class="note note-error">This is a required field.</div>
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" id="target2" placeholder="Organization / Company Name" name="companyname">
                                <div class="note note-error">This is a required field.</div>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <section class="col col-6">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-company"></i>
                                <input type="text" id="target3" placeholder="Location" name="location" >
                                <div class="note note-error">This is a required field.</div>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                     </div>             
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>  

                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Tell us about your company background
                            <textarea id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"  name="background" placeholder="Tell us about your company background"></textarea>CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

var textarea = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement( 'textarea' ) );
CKEDITOR.replace( textarea );
                        </label>
                    </section>                  
                    <section>
                        <label class="textarea">

                            Job Summary
                            <textarea id="editor2" rows="10" cols="80"  name="summary" placeholder="Job Summary"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </section>
                </fieldset>
                <footer>
                    <p>Fill all fields to activate the submit button.</br>
                    Thanks</p><i class="fa fa-check" style="float: right; position: relative; right: 22px; color: white; z-index: 1; padding-top: 23px;"></i><input 
                    class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"

                    id="sbtbtn" />

                   <div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><?php
                   include "../module/back.php";
                   ?></div>
                    </footer>
            </form>
```

**CKEditor call**

```
 <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
```

Comment: You'd better remove the meaningless part of your code to emphasis the question.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    on: {
        change: function() {
            var inst = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];
            if (inst.getData() != '') {
                $('#sbtbtn').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#sbtbtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Bound the change event on initalizing, and get data by `CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData()`

See the document:
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-on

Comment: can you please do it in a jsfiddle.com

Comment: Too much work, I think it's clear enough for you, just replace this part of code into your js part as shown. I will work.

Comment: waiting for your responce

Comment: yes, it didn't worked, i placed your codes in JS field.

Comment: I can't find a ckeditor cdn, so can't do in jsfiddle.

Comment: Try on your own computer.

Comment: You check it, it may be other other problem, anyway the code works in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Use the newest edition of ckeditor and retry. I won't debug for you.

Comment: thanks @AlfredHuang your solution perfectly works!